# JavaScript Constants

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object

we know we can protect the value of variables , so user can't change the value of variables the existing!! Does implementation this have nothing wrong with object..??

for example..

```
const x = 5;

x = 10;

alert(x)
// will be returned 5
```

using an object..

```
 const obj = {
        init: function() {
         obj.show()
      },
      show: function() {
       //..
      },
      hide: function() {
      //..
      }
  }
  obj.init();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can get away with using JS5, you have this option:

```
var CONST = {
  NAME: "The Cool Gizmo",
  VERSION: 2
};
Object.freeze(CONST);

alert(CONST.NAME);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  var myObj = (function () {
    var privVar1 = 111,
        privVar2 = 222;

    var getConstants = function () {

        return { priv1: privVar1, priv2: privVar2 }
    };
    return { getConstants: getConstants };
})();

myObj.getConstants().priv1
```

Answer (score 1):

The const keyword is not currently supported by all browsers, nor is it a part of the official Javascript specification in use today. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

To accomplish a constant, consider encapsulating the behavior you need in a function:

```
var getConstant = function(key) {
    var constants = { x: 5 };        
    return constants[key];
};

alert(getConstant("x"));
```

---

Or, simply use a variable with the appropriate scope to protect 3rd parties from setting its value:

```
function myModule() {
    var x = 5;
    doSomethingWith(x);
}
```